# React Native ListView onEndReached doesn't called

Tags: listview, react-native

I want to implement infinite scroll so I do this in my ListView tag

```
renderRow(data){
    return (
        <CardSection>
            <Text>
                {data.id}
            </Text>
        </CardSection>
    );
}

<ListView 
    dataSource={this.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}
    onEndReached = {this.loadMoreNews.bind(this)}
    pageSize = {5}
/>
```

I get 5 data every fetch action that I call in loadMoreNews() and componentWillMount. Because the first 5 data doesn't fill the entire screen I expected that onEndReached to be called automatically since it already in the end of the ListView, but it doesn't.

I tried to style the Text tag in renderRow into this

```
renderRow(data){
    return (
        <CardSection>
            <Text style={{height:100}}>
                {data.id}
            </Text>
        </CardSection>
    );
}
```

and it works as i want. I'm afraid that my renderRow won't fill the entire screen if my aplication is running in the wide screen device.

Is it the behavior of ListView or I missed something? What is the solution? I don't really want to force my component to be very big so it always fill the entire screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare component contentsize with height of the device and call loadMoreNews fn.

```
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

<ListView 
   dataSource={this.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderRow}
   onLayout={(event) => {
      var layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
      if(layout.height < deviceHeight) this.loadMoreNews()
   }}
   onEndReached = {this.loadMoreNews.bind(this)}
   pageSize = {5}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> onEndReached?: function
>
> Called when all rows have been rendered and the list has been scrolled
>   to within onEndReachedThreshold of the bottom. The native scroll event
>   is provided.

It won't be automatically called unless user swipes the listview (wide screen scenario).

You may [set a threshold](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#onendreachedthreshold) to trigger onEndReached without reaching the bottom end of the screen.

> onEndReachedThreshold: number
>
> Threshold in pixels (virtual, not physical) for calling onEndReached.

**Alternatively**, you can manually call `loadMoreNews()` when your screen isn't fully covered by rows. To do so, just measure the height of the CardSection component, and divide `Dimensions.get('window').height` to that, which gives you number CardSection components that can fit into the current screen.

If your rows don't have a fixed height that you can know, you may use [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) function.